# git: unable to cherry pick

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I am caught up in a weird loop while trying to cherry pick. Here is what I do, and where the problem is.

I have two branches: **mainline**, and **temp**. I want to cherry-pick a specific commit from mainline to temp. I am doing this like follows.

1. `git checkout temp`
2. `git cherry pick <commit sha>`
3. Now, I get: `Segmentation fault: 11`
4. I rerun the command from 2), and get: `Unable to create ...git/index.lock': File exists`

   ====================================================================
5. Now I run `rm -f ./.git/index.lock`
6. Try again `git cherry pick <commit sha>`
7. Now I get this:

   *error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
       myfile.java*

... for a file which isn't even there. I had it before, but I renamed it, so file under that name is not in a repository.

8. I run `git status` and now I see the file *myfile.java* under **untracked files**. And now it even appears in the editor. I can delete it from the editor, but can't delete it from git repository. I get `pathspec 'myfile.java' did not match any files`
9. OK, so I delete the file from editor, rerun `cherry-pick` and I am back to step **3)**.

What is happening here, and how can I just do my cherry-pick? :D

Comment: Are you using git on Windows by any chance?

Comment: You shouldn't `rm .git/index.lock` but use `git cherry-pick --abort` to return the repository to the previous state before trying again.

Comment: @fedepad No, mac.

Comment: uhmm, because I could have understood the segfault in that case maybe, since [git_windows_issue_checryr_pick](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/952)

Comment: @axiac If I do that: error: no cherry-pick or revert in progress

Comment: `git clean -xdf` will force repository clean up. Everything not tracked will be removed (be careful and do backup whatever you want to be kept beforehand).

Comment: Did you really run "cherry pick" or was it "cherry-pick"?

Comment: @max630 I ran cherry-pick :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have a segmentation fault. I suggest to make sure you work with the latest git version.

A different way to cherry pick would be to create a patch from the commit and apply it:

```
git checkout temp
git format-patch -1 <commit sha>
git apply 0001.....patch
```

Comment: The segmentation fault is the least of my problems. If I just rerun the command, it goes away but different error appears (step 4.). Not sure what patch is, I have never used that.

Comment: A patch file is just a text file containing the changes of the commit. Similar output to `git diff`. Then git knows how to apply the patch on your working directory.

Comment: And what is this 0001... ?

Comment: This solution can work, since it avoids using cherry pick, which seems the problem.

Comment: @wesleyy The 0001...patch is the generated patch file from the previous `git format-patch` command.

Comment: @wesleyy The segmentation fault is the first of your problems. The other problems are just consequences of it. As you state yourself: when you have fixed the latter, you are back at the former. Perhaps you want to bring the matter to the git mailing list. Just write to `git@vger.kernel.org`. Be sure to include the output of `GIT_TRACE=2 git cherry-pick that-commit-sha1` and include the version you are using (`git version`).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to homebrew git 2.11.1 fixed the issue for me.

Based on the output messages and the dialogue on [this pull request](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/952) for git-for-windows which was subsequently raised upstream, and this [mailing list thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/89ffd6eaf4e1e121426c84f31dfc9c289f2a948b.1480091758.git.johannes.schindelin@gmx.de/T/) it appears for some reason the return value from `refresh_cache_entry()` is null which causes the segmentation fault (in my case the paths I was cherry-picking onto do not exist on the branch I am on)

Here's what happened for me:

```
$ git cherry-pick d4c26fc1
Segmentation fault: 11

$ git cherry-pick --abort
error: no cherry-pick or revert in progress
fatal: cherry-pick failed

$ rm .git/index.lock

$ brew upgrade git
Updating Homebrew...
...
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.11.1: 1,456 files, 32.4M

$ git cherry-pick d4c26fc1
error: addinfo_cache failed for path 'foo/bar/baz'
error: could not apply d4c26fc... Some commit subject
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```